# POP3 protocol but not getting unread mails correctly

Tags: java, api, email, jakarta-mail, javax

I have some code to download attachments from unread mails the code downloading attachments properly,But it is downloading attachment from a certain date, it should download attachment from unread mails only.below i am attaching code.

```
    package filread.oneline;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

/**
 * This program demonstrates how to download e-mail messages and save
 * attachments into files on disk.
 *
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class EmailAttachmentReceiver {
    private String saveDirectory;

    /**
     * Sets the directory where attached files will be stored.
     * @param dir absolute path of the directory
     */
    public void setSaveDirectory(String dir) {
        this.saveDirectory = dir;
    }

    /**
     * Downloads new messages and saves attachments to disk if any.
     * @param host
     * @param port
     * @param userName
     * @param password
     */
    public void downloadEmailAttachments(String host, String port,
            String userName, String password) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        // server setting
       properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",true);
       properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
       properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
        // SSL setting
      // properties.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
       properties.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", false);


      //  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

      // properties.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",String.valueOf(port));

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try {
            // connects to the message store
            Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
            store.connect("mail.vidalhealthtpa.com",userName, password);

            // opens the inbox folder
            Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folderInbox.getUnreadMessageCount());

            // fetches new messages from server
           // Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();
            Message[]  arrayMessages = folderInbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));


            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
                Message message = arrayMessages[i];
                Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
                String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
                String subject = message.getSubject();
                String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

                String contentType = message.getContentType();
                String messageContent = "";

                // store attachment file name, separated by comma
                String attachFiles = "";

                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                    // content may contain attachments
                    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                            // this part is attachment
                            String fileName = part.getFileName();
                            attachFiles += fileName + ", ";

                           byte[] abcd=IOUtils.toByteArray(part.getInputStream());
                           System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folderInbox.getUnreadMessageCount());

                           System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folderInbox.getNewMessageCount());

                           System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folderInbox.getMessageCount());
                           System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + arrayMessages.length);


                           FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName), abcd);



                          //  part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);

                        } else {
                            // this part may be the message content
                            messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                        attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                    }
                } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
                        || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                    Object content = message.getContent();
                    if (content != null) {
                        messageContent = content.toString();
                    }
                }

                // print out details of each message
                System.out.println("Message #" + (i + 1) + ":");
                System.out.println("\t From: " + from);
                System.out.println("\t Subject: " + subject);
                System.out.println("\t Sent Date: " + sentDate);
                System.out.println("\t Message: " + messageContent);
                System.out.println("\t Attachments: " + attachFiles);
            }

            // disconnect
            folderInbox.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            System.out.println("No provider for pop3.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs this program with Gmail POP3 server
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "host";
        String port = "110";
        String userName = "username";
        String password = "password";

        String saveDirectory = "D:/Attachment";

        EmailAttachmentReceiver receiver = new EmailAttachmentReceiver();
        receiver.setSaveDirectory(saveDirectory);
        receiver.downloadEmailAttachments(host, port, userName, password);

    }
}
```

I can't able to guess what issue ,why the code is not reading UNREAD MAILS only, its reading all mails and downloading all attachments.

Answer (score 2):

The POP3 protocol doesn't support any message flags so there's no way to know what messages are read or unread.  See the [com.sun.mail.pop3 package documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html) for more information.

If at all possible, you should use the IMAP protocol.

Comment: Thank you!  Can I use imap protocol for pop3 type server.  Because my server is accepting only pop 3 protocol. If possible to change protocol then how can we change it.

Comment: Nope.  If your server doesn't support imap, you can't use it.

Comment: Ok, Now I get to know my server can accept IMAP also but sir actually i have written code for IMAP also , i am getting same issue ,after setting flag also i am not getting unread mails only.

Comment: Fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), update your code above, and post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) if it still doesn't work.  Note that you need to open the folder read/write to change the flags.

Comment: Sir i posted my answer now it is working properly.Thank you so much for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

```
package MAIL.READ.ATTACHEMENT;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;







import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;
import javax.mail.search.SearchTerm;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class ReadMailAttachement {
    private String saveDirectory;

    public void setSaveDirectory(String dir) {
        this.saveDirectory = dir;
    }

    public void downloadEmailAttachments(String host, String port,
            String userName, String password) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        // server setting
    /*  properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",true);*/
     properties.put("mail.imap.host", host);
   //  properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
     /* properties.put("mail.imap.port", port);
       */
        // SSL setting
 /*     properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", false);*/


      //  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

      // properties.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",String.valueOf(port));

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try {
             Store store = session.getStore("imap");
            store.connect("mail.vidalhealthtpa.com",userName, password);
            Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folderInbox.getUnreadMessageCount());


          Message[] arrayMessages1 = folderInbox.getMessages();
         Message[]  arrayMessages = folderInbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false),arrayMessages1);

        System.out.println("    jjj  arrayMessages.length 0   "+arrayMessages.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
                Message message = arrayMessages[i];
                Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
                String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
                String subject = message.getSubject();
                String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

               message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);

                String contentType = message.getContentType();
                String messageContent = "";

                // store attachment file name, separated by pipeline
                String attachFiles = "|";

                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                    // content may contain attachments
                    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {

                            // this part is attachment
                            String fileName = part.getFileName();
                            attachFiles += fileName + "|";




                           byte[] FileByteData=IOUtils.toByteArray(part.getInputStream());
                         FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName), FileByteData);







                          //  part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);

                        } else {
                            // this part may be the message content
                            messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                        }
                    }

                   /* if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                        attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                    }*/

                } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")|| contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                    Object content = message.getContent();
                    if (content != null) {
                        messageContent = content.toString();
                    }
                }

                // print out details of each message
                System.out.println("Message #" + (i + 1) + ":");
                System.out.println("\t From: " + from);
                System.out.println("\t Subject: " + subject);
                System.out.println("\t Sent Date: " + sentDate);
                System.out.println("\t Message: " + messageContent);
                System.out.println("\t Attachments: " + attachFiles);
            }

            folderInbox.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            System.out.println("No provider for pop3.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "host";
        String port = "110";
        //String userName = "user";
       // String password = "password";

        String userName = "rishabh.keshari";
        String password = "TuY$&Q130";

        String saveDirectory = "D:/Attachment";

        ReadMailAttachement receiver = new ReadMailAttachement();
        receiver.setSaveDirectory(saveDirectory);
        receiver.downloadEmailAttachments(host, port, userName, password);

    }
}
```

I am setting flag seen as a true for read mail

```
message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
```